# Django - Adding Css Classes To Form Field Options, Dynamically

Tags: django, django-forms

This is one of those things that might be dead simple, and I'm just missing it, or it might just be very difficult. Not sure yet, but I know I haven't found the dead simple way to do it.

I've got an extension of ModelMultipleChoiceField, and I'd like to put some CSS classes on the individual option rows - I'd like each row to get its class from the object that it's selecting. Specifically, I'm selecting volunteer opportunities, and I'd like to color-code them by day. A given Event (for example, a volunteer opportunity) knows when it starts, so I can get the date from the event, and obviously I can slap a @property on it to have it spit out just a string like "friday" but I can't see how to ask the field to organize itself so that each option gets a class added to it by referring to that property.

I've also tried writing the template to produce itself with this styling, but that's become very painful, and hasn't worked very well, and will probably be a pain point down the road in terms of maintenance, so I'd like to do this further up if I can.

Comment: Note that it's the widget, not the field, which is responsible for rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had to customise a lot of django forms, I feel your pain. I think I understand what you're trying to do, and I believe there is a solution.

In `django.forms.models`, the widget defined for `ModelMultipleChoiceField` is `SelectMultiple`, which lives in `django.forms.widgets`. This is responsible for the rendering of the entire widget, but if you look inside the `render` method for the widget, it is essentially wrapping the results of `render_options` inside of the `<select>` HTML element.

The `render_options` method is on the parent `Select` widget, which in turn is calling the `render_option` method on the same class. This is where the actual HTML for each `<option>` element is being rendered, and where you can hook in to add the HTML attributes. You're provided the `option_value` attribute here, so you can check whatever you have to and determine what attribute/s you wish to include in the HTML. You'll be responsible for returning the HTML, so you can copy/pasta the function and modify as you wish (this is why this is painful). See [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.3/django/forms/widgets.py#L519) on github for reference.

You'll have to define a widget subclass of `SelectMultiple` for this and assign it as the widget to your field; to do this, do something like below (depending on whether you need any runtime params for your widget instance or not):

```
class MyWidgetSubclass(SelectMultiple):

    def render_option(selected_choices, option_value, option_label):

        my_fancy_new_html_for_the_option = ...
        ... your code here ...
        return my_fancy_new_html_for_the_option

class MyForm(Form):

    my_field = ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=MyWidgetSubclass)

    # or

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs):  # Not the real params, of course

       super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       # You'll probably need to pass arguments to the instantiation.
       self.fields['my_field'].widget = MyWidgetSubclass()
```

So yes, this is pretty hacky and would like to know if there is an easier way to do this. If there is, I'd be happy to know, as we've had to do this in a few places at our workplace and it feels dirty every time (mixing markup with functionality is not my favourite). You could completely override the `render()` method of the widget to do something custom, but this is probably the least changes you're going to be able to make to get it up and running.